# How to add home screen functionality in php

Tags: javascript, homescreen, manifest.json

I am using PHP. And I want functionality **'add to home screen'**. I read some blogs and did some code, but still it is not working.

My file structure is this:
[image]

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template One</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer template1">
        hello
    </div>
 </body>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
 console.log("Will the service worker register?");
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
  .then(function(reg){
    console.log("Yes, it did.");
 }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
});
}
</script>
</html>
```

manifest.json is:

```
{
"short_name": "digbiz_screen",
"name": "Larage name Digbiz",
"theme_color": "#4A90E2",
"background_color": "#F7F8F9",
"display": "standalone",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "chat1.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "48x48"
},
{
  "src": "chat1.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "96x96"
},
{
  "src": "chat1.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "144x144"
},
{
  "src": "chat1.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
}
],
"start_url": "/?utm_source=launcher"
}
```

**service-worker.js is empty.**

When I reload on chrome. It is not working.

Am I going on correct way. Please give any solution.